# SSRS Break after set amount of rows not behaving as expected

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping, rowcount, row-number

I am working on SSRS in Visual Studio 2012.
I have a set of data that I need to break after every 16 rows.
Using examples I found, I create a group on the details that groups on the following expression:

```
=CInt(Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing) / 16))
```

Then I set page break to at the start of every group.
(Also tried it with Floor and then at the end of every group)

Instead of displaying 16 rows and then adding a page break, I am only getting a single row (every sixteenth row) on each page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you put more info about your report design, data and groupings?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the post you found this solution from?
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prakasht/archive/2013/07/04/limits-the-number-of-records-per-page-in-ssrs-2012.aspx

=int((RowNumber(nothing)-1)/16)

Works for me, but you need to follow the instructions in his post to a T. I think the key is creating the parent group above the details.